# Mermaid JS wrap links from far right to far left

Tags: javascript, flowchart, mermaid

Working with Mermaid js to make flowcharts and can't seem to find a way to wrap links around to a new "line" so to speak.  Docs and Googling haven't gotten me anywhere.  Does anyone know if it is possible to create a link to replace the red line?

[image]

Comment: Can you maybe show your current code? It would be much easier to help you.

Comment: Any graph of the type `A --> B --> B --> B --> B --> B --> B --> B` where there are too many nodes to fit vertically, so you want to force a line break at a specific point.

Comment: [Can I control the direction of flowcharts in Mermaid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66631182/can-i-control-the-direction-of-flowcharts-in-mermaid)